# jquery object - function undefined error

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following function, my objects inside floatShareBar function is undefined. Do I have to init or define a var before the functions? it throws me js error : .float - function undefined.

```
   (function($) {
.
.
.

    $("body").on("ab.snap", function(event) {
        if (event.snapPoint >= 768) {
            floatShareBar.float()
        } else {
            floatShareBar.unfloat();
        }
    });

    var floatShareBar = function() {
        var fShareBar = $('#article-share');

        this.float =  function() {
            console.log(
        };
        this.unfloat = function() {
            console.log("unfloat");
        };
    };
.
.
.

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: That's not a "jQuery object".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get an instance of that function with a self instantiating call:

```
var floatShareBar = (function() {
    var fShareBar = $('#article-share');

    this.float =  function() {
        console.log('float');
    };
    this.unfloat = function() {
        console.log("unfloat");
    };

    return this;
})();
```

UPDATE 1: I modified it to create an object within the function to attach those functions to, since in the previous example `this` refers to the `window` object

```
var floatShareBar = (function() {
    var fShareBar = $('#article-share');
    var instance = {};

    instance.float =  function() {
        console.log('float');
    };
    instance.unfloat = function() {
        console.log("unfloat");
    };

    return instance;
})();
```

UPDATE 2: You can actually just use the `new` keyword as well, [look here for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript)

```
var floatShareBar = new (function() {
    var fShareBar = $('#article-share');

    this.float =  function() {
        console.log('float');
    };
    this.unfloat = function() {
        console.log("unfloat");
    };
})();
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but the problem is that `this` refers to the window object, not the function itself. It's probably not the intention to add functions to the window object.

Comment: @Juhana learn something new every day.. I guess that makes sense since there is no 'owner' of the function yet when declared thusly

Comment: thanks. so, when I call the function from body.on, should i call as instance.float or floatsharebar.float?

Comment: `floatShareBar.float()`, `instance` only exists within the closure

Answer (score -1):

Change you function to this:

```
$("body").on("ab.snap", function(event) {
        if (event.snapPoint >= 768) {
            (new floatShareBar()).float()
        } else {
            (new floatShareBar()).unfloat();
        }
    });

function floatShareBar () {
        var fShareBar = $('#article-share');

        this.float =  function() {
            console.log(
        };
        this.unfloat = function() {
            console.log("unfloat");
        };
    };
```

you should declare functions when using **var** before you call them.